# 2 Alerts getting created for same item in sharepoint 2013

Tags: alert

We are facing a wierd issue while creating alerts on an item in sharepoint 2013. While creating an alert on an item, 2 alerts are getting creating for the same item. 
Steps to reproduce:

1) Add a document in document library

2) "Check out" the document added.

3) Create an alert on that item.

When we go to "Manage my Alerts", we see that 2 alerts are created for that item whereas, what we want is 1 alert.

When you "check in" the item, alert count goes back to 1 from 2!

We were able to replicate the above issue from both code and OOB.

Is this a bug in SharePoint or are we missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a built in feature to remind you to check back in the item.  So once you check out the item its basically creating an alert to remind you to check the item in at such and such time, and when you check it back in, it removes it.

I can tell you one of the pains in 2010 with a document library was people checking out documents and not checking them in.

Comment: yea...but alert is not automatically created for the item when its checked out. When you exlicitly add an alert on the item, this issue occurs!